How to make cookiecutter prompts work better on Databricks?
I’m using cookiecutter to create project templates on Databricks, but I’ve been having trouble with the prompts.
As far as I know, in Databricks notebooks, the usual cookiecutter prompts don’t display properly, making it hard for users to know what input to provide. For example, users can’t see what question they’re answering, which often leads to errors or confusion
For now, the only workaround that I was able to think of is to create a function to handle the inputs by explicitly asking for each value, printing the prompt, and then passing the responses to cookiecutter as extra_context.  The inputs themselves are already defined in the cookiecutter.json file in the repository (repo_url). Here’s what I’ve done so far:
def get_user_input():
   project_date = input("What is your project date? YYYYMMDD: ")
   client = input("What is your client name?: ")
   id_project = input("What is your project ID? XXX: ")
   return {
       "project_date ": project_date ,
       "client": client ,
       "id_project ": id_project 
   }

cookiecutter(
    repo_url,
    directory='databricks',
    no_input=True,
    extra_context=get_user_input()
)

I’m not sure if this is the best solution so I am looking for a way to make the prompts clearer and avoid writing the wrong input.
